# Maven 2.2 site description xml tags

Tags: maven-2

I've tried to find what attributes can take the 'menu' xml-tag.

The problem: I want to show the reports like javadoc, findbugs, tests, clover/cobertura, etc. 
I use the following site descriptor (site.xml)

```
<project>
  <bannerLeft>
  <name>API</name>
  </bannerLeft>
  <body>    
    <menu name="Project">
      <item name="Purpose" href="/purpose.html"/>      
    </menu> 
    <menu name="Reports"/>
      ${reports}
  </body>
</project>
```

The wanted reports are in the correponding pom.

Any advice?

Thank you in advance
Manel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using:

```
<menu ref="reports"/>
```

instead of:

```
<menu name="Reports"/>
  ${reports}
```

The `<menu ref="reports"/>` element will be replaced by a menu with links to all the generated reports for your project. Take a look at the [Maven: Creating a site](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-site.html) guide for more information.

Also, if you want to see what elements/attributes are allowed in `site.xml` check out the  XML Schema which is published at http://maven.apache.org/xsd/decoration-1.0.0.xsd. There is an [XML Schema Reference](http://maven.apache.org/doxia/doxia-sitetools/doxia-decoration-model/decoration.html) for the site descriptor available too.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but this one doesn't work. Maybe the configuration in the pom isn't correct. I'll check this one. Cheers. Manel